# How do I use Instagram's API to display a gallery of my own photos?

Tags: api, instagram

I'd like to use Instagram's API to display a gallery of just my own photos on a webpage.  Is this possible?

Comment: I found this step by step tutorial very useful https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/01/display-instagram-feed-website.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Most of the endpoints require users to be authenticated. You can retrieve tagged pictures and popular pictures without authentication. In order to display your own, you would need a user to be logged in with Instagram.

**EDIT:** Check this out: http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1 - Use Instagram API**

No you don't always need the Access Token. You can also use the Client ID like in this API request -
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT-ID

User Photos Endpoint - 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT-ID

You will need to replace your User ID in the above URL. The output will be a JSON response so you will have to display the photos yourself.

**Method 2 - Use a Plugin**

You can directly use a plugin that will embed your Photos from your Instagram Account onto your website. A good Example would be - InstaMax plugin which will display all your photos, videos with likes and comments.

A small Demo of the plugin is present here - http://demos.codehandling.com/instamax_demo/instamax_live_edit.html

**Update 2016**

Method 1 will not work after June 2016 due to changes in Instagram API. You need to have you app approved from Instagram and then generate an Access Token.

1. Generating the Token is the easy part. You can simple use the below API from your browser -

   https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
2. Frankly, the hardest part is getting your APP approved from Instagram. It took me a month and several rejections to understand what their platform policies are and how to send the request for approval.

I would recommend you to use a plugin that already has an approved App so that you can use their App to generate Tokens for their plugin.

Comment: Method 1 doesn't seem to work any more. I guess due to changes in the Instagram api.

Comment: @Garg's If you are adding as a web app, then no change. If you are adding natively in Java or something, then you will have to re-code the whole thing. The Instagram API links and response formats in the plugin will remain the same.

Comment: The response to the URL in the 1st point: Implicit authentication is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery latest version from CDN and then:

```
 $(document).ready(function{
    var token = 'Your Access Token', 
        userid = 'Your User ID',
        num_photos = 10; // how much photos you want to get

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            for( n in data.data ){                  
                $('body').append('<div><img src="'+data.data[n].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></div>');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

[DEMO](https://mavidunyakres.com/fotograflar)

Comment: this uses the old API endpoints which will be deprecated as of June 29th.