# Show User's Instagram Photos on website

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to show my latest photos on my website. I used to do it on previous version of Instagram API, but now that it changed I can't.

I created an app on the Instagram Account, and did all authenticate steps as described on the docs, but it always shows me a screen asking for the user login. But I need to show the pictures even the user is not logged, is it possible in this new API version?

PS. I'm using PHP on server-side.

Thanks.

Comment: add the code snippet and the response from the api

Comment: I am doing as described in the docs. I'm accessing this address with right client_id and redirect_url: 

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

And it shows me a login and auth screen.

The problem is that I need an access token to show the photos, but I can't get it without loggin in.

Comment: so you want to show all your photos to the person visiting your site correct

Comment: Yes, That's correct.

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful to you, but I stumbled across [this site](https://lightwidget.com/), which offers free instagram feed widgets that you can embed on your site.  They have updated their app to comply with Instagram's new API changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get user's all instagram post by his authentication. Without authentication you can not user's data in new api system. In new api , you can get his post image url and save it in your database. Then you can show image by those url.

Comment: I see. But isn't it possible to show my own photos in my own website for all people who is not looged? Can't I do as I did before when I could log in using a token and don't ask the viewer to login?

Comment: After login you can get your own authentication token. By using that token you can show image to every one.

Comment: So, I need my user to log in before seeing my pictures. I just get this token if they log in. I can't login myself and save this token for everyone.

Comment: No you dont need to do that. You just need to save your own token. Your user can see your image by your authentication token

Comment: Unfortunetly I can't do it... See what their website says: 

The Instagram API requires authentication - specifically requests made on behalf of a user. Authenticated requests require an access_token. These tokens are unique to a user and should be stored securely. Access tokens may expire at any time in the future. ... do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

Comment: The way you said is  the legal way. Go to https://apigee.com/console/instagram create your token. Use your token to show your photos to others. Update this every week. Though it was a very bad way.

Comment: :/ Ok. Unfortunetly I couldn't do this way. It's a client website, and I can't do it for all websites I do. I think I'll have to stop showing Instagram photos on website.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }
  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE");
  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    // Do something with this data.
  }
?>
```

[source](http://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified)

Comment: Great! This part is ok to me, but how to get an access_token? The API just give this token if the user is logged and accept the app in his account. I need to show the pictures to all my visitors.

Comment: @LeonardoOberle check the source link there an example given there

Comment: I see. But the problem is that if I do like it says, my visitor need to log in the instagram and accept the terms of the app before seeing my pictures. Can't I show my pictures in my website for not logged users anymore? Even my pictures are all public?
I don't see how to do it.

Comment: @LeonardoOberle have you implement this logic

Comment: @LeonardoOberle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478772/how-do-i-use-instagrams-api-to-display-a-gallery-of-my-own-photos

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's not good to me. I want to show my public pictures and don't ask people to login and accept terms for that.
Just to let you know how my website works, I show the pictures from instagram and my tweets in my footer, and I would like people could see my pictures as they see my tweets.
Twitter doens't ask me to make my users login to see my tweets and it uses oauth also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97196/discussion-between-leonardo-oberle-and-saurabh-kamble).